# Cannot add View To the relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

i am making a activity that takes int position from another activity to get a class formula that have the formula, some variables and the title , so i want to create the activity by taking that formula and setting the title , making some edit text views for variables so that the user add values for them and then i return the result by a dialogue the problem is that the views that i add programitically are not displayed, plz help

```
  public class DisplayFomula extends AppCompatActivity {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_fomula);
    DB db = new DB(this);
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    int pos = extra.getInt("id");
    final Formula form = db.getFormula(pos);
    RelativeLayout layout=new RelativeLayout(this);
    TextView tw1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    tw1.setText(form.title);

    final String[] var = form.var;
    int i=0;
    final EditText[] ed = new EditText[50];
    for(;i<var.length;i++){
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ed[i]= new EditText(this);
    ed[i].setId(i);
        ed[i].setHint(var[i]);
        ed[i].setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

    ed[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        if(i!=0) params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,ed[i-1].getId());
        else params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.textView11);
    layout.addView(ed[i],params);}
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btn.setId(i);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    btn.setLayoutParams(params);
    btn.setText("Go!");
    layout.addView(btn,params);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    addContentView(layout,params);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double[] varin=new double[var.length];
            for(int i =0;i<var.length;i++){
                Double dbl = Double.parseDouble(ed[i].getText().toString());
                varin[i]=dbl;
            }
            String res = String.valueOf(form.result(varin));


        }
    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all the views to RelativeLayout layout. But i think u have'nt add layout view to any activity_display_fomula view.
get a viewgroup from activity_display_fomula  and add your RelativeLayout layout to it..

Comment: thx but the edittexts are not displaying , only first one and the btn is displayed nt the others which are added by the loop

Comment: plz help waiting for the reply